# Find all solutions of $x^3\equiv 5 \pmod{3\cdot 11}\,$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So the first step is obviously splitting into two congruences.

$$x^3 \equiv 5 \pmod 3 \quad\text{and}\quad x^3 \equiv 5 \pmod{11}.$$

First is to find primitive roots of $U_3$ and $U_{11}$.

2 is a primitive root for both groups.

Comment: Why do you need primitive roots to solve the problem?

Comment: There is a formula to solve these types of congruences using primitive roots. Ill write it out in a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^3=5\pmod 3\iff x^3=2\pmod 3\iff x=2\pmod 3$$

$$x^3=5\pmod{11}\iff x=3\pmod{11}$$

Well, now apply CRT to both rightmost congruencies...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 3\!:\ x^3\!\equiv 5\equiv -1\:\Rightarrow\:x\equiv \color{#C00}{-1}.\:$ By little Fermat,$\rm\:mod\ 11\!:\ x\not\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:x^{10}\equiv 1,\:$ therefore $\rm\:x^{-1}\!\equiv x^9\equiv(x^3)^3\!\equiv 5^3\!\equiv 4,\:$ hence $\rm\:x\equiv 1/4\equiv 12/4\equiv \color{#0A0}3$. Now one can apply CRT to combine the solutions, or, more simply,  $\rm\: 5\equiv \color{#0A0}3^3\ (mod\ 11),\,$ $\rm\,5\equiv \color{#C00}{11}^3\ (mod\ 3)\:\Rightarrow\:5\equiv (3\!+\!11)^3\ (mod\ 33),\:$ by

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\rm\:a,b\:$ are coprime integers and $\rm\:f\in\Bbb Z[x]\:$ then

$$\rm \begin{eqnarray} x\,\equiv\, f(b)\ \ \ (mod\ a)\\ \rm x\,\equiv\,f(a)\ \ \ (mod\ b)\end{eqnarray}\ \iff\ x\,\equiv\, f(a\!+\!b)\ \ \ (mod\ ab)$$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ (\Leftarrow)\ \ mod\ a\!:\ a\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:x \equiv f(a\!+\!b)\equiv f(b),\:$ since $\rm\:x\equiv c\,\ (mod\ ab)\:\Rightarrow\:x\equiv c\,\ (mod\ a).$ Conversely, as in CRT, the solution $\rm\:x \equiv f(a\!+\!b)\:$ is necessarily unique $\rm\:mod\ ab,\:$ since if $\rm\:x,x'\:$ are solutions then $\rm\:a,b\mid x-x'\:\Rightarrow\:lcm(a,b)=ab\mid x-x'$.